# using json format to communicate between android and servlet

Tags: android, json, servlets

I want to send data in json format to a servlet from my android client. Can it be done? If so what is the advantage of using json.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can send and retrieve data using json format from Android to a web service.
In Android use can use [GSon](http://code.google.com/p/google-gson/) to parse data to send to web service.

Advantage of using JSon is to minimize the data transferring, then it is faster

Comment: If you are comparing with xml format, it is yes because of overhead of syntax. If you simply are sending a simple message, you can just add it to http entity and send it. However, json still is a better choice for readable. I have used Google Map API and I see even a status OK, they are using json. Hope this helps

Comment: **Why to use GSon (third-party API) if there are already native-classes provided by Android itself?**

Comment: @Cuong Thai : One final question. My android client takes user details and want to send to servlet. Can you pls give a sample code showing this.

Comment: @Paresh Mayani: Can you please elaborate?

Comment: There are native classes/methods to implement JSON Parsing. So if we are having such resource then why to use third-party API such as GSon. Here i have written detailed example for [Android - JSON Parsing example](http://www.technotalkative.com/android-json-parsing/)

Comment: @PareshMayani: GSon is a library allowing you to map a java object to json without manually parsing each json object. You simply create a couple of class and define a way to parse. You can find all sample in GSon project page

Comment: @user1139023: You can serialize the object to string and send it to your servlet
https://sites.google.com/site/gson/gson-user-guide#TOC-Primitives-Examples